# xHTML renders locally but when on a web site it downloads it as a file when using Chrome, or Opera

Tags: google-chrome, opera, rendering, xhtml

Below is the xHTML listing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"[]>
<html xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html:head>
<html:meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />
<html:title>
Page Title</html:title>
<html:meta name="keywords" content="Stuff the page is about" />
<html:meta name="description" content="Great little webpage" />
<html:script type="text/javascript" />
</html:head>
<html:body>
<html:table height="800px" width="100%">
<html:tr style="height:798px;">
<html:td />
<html:td height="100%" width="1100px">
<html:iframe height="100%" src="CapabilitiesList.htm" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" />
</html:td>
<html:td />
</html:tr>
</html:table>
</html:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using either or both of some kind of special management and publication system, or is this supposed to be a regular xhtml file?

Comment: What is the extension of your file? Maybe the web server selects the wrong MIME type.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to define the namespace for a basic XHTML file. In fact the namespace is assumed to be XHTML in a typical web-page file.

The part that is wrong is where you prefix every element name with `html:`.

Also, there were a couple of errors. You cant have height and width attributes for tables and the meta attribute *charset* is redundant. Spot five differences:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" />

  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="keywords" content="Stuff the page is about" />
  <meta name="description" content="Great little webpage" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr style="height:798px;">
      <td></td>

      <td><iframe height="100%" src="CapabilitiesList.htm" width=
      "100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></td>

      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem remains without the namespace and without the prefix. the page renders when I call it from a local drive but from a website it downloads the file instead of rendering it. Note that IE will render the page from a website.

Comment: There are two likely causes. There is a non-utf8 character in your file or there are syntactical errors. The [online validation service](http://validator.w3.org/check) suggests syntax error